# Total Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, gcd-and-lcm

How many sets of size $5$ exist from the first $n$ natural numbers such that each element in the combination is pairwise coprime. eg. $\{1,2,3,5,7\}$ ,$\{1,4,3,5,7\}$ etc. but $\{1,2,4,5,7\}$ is invalid because $\mbox{gcd}(2,4)=2$.

Comment: It seems there could not be a simple formula to count these sets, depending on $n$ in an exact way.  An asymptotic estimate as $n$ tends to infinity seems doable, or a recursive formula that depends on the prime factors of $n$ together with values of a similar function for smaller size sets and smaller integers than $n$.  It would improve your Question to tell Readers why you are interested in this.

Comment: What if i know the answer for size 4 ? can't that be used to calculate for size 5. Also N is very small at most 50

Comment: Tentatively, an answer in terms of the number of primes among the first $n$ natural numbers seems very doable.

Comment: Even for the simple case of pairs of positive integers less than $n$ I only know an approximate fraction (the limit of the ratio of coprime pairs to all pairs as $n$ tends to infinity).

Comment: Do you have any idea related to mobius function for this calculation. I read at many sources that this can help.

Comment: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790284/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-coprime-subsets-of-the-set-1-2-3-n ..Can this solution be restricted for size  5

Comment: It would be easy to write a program to count such sets for $n\le 50$.  Is that something you'd be interested in?

Comment: Yes..i wanted to write a program. Can you help. Till i have done that i have only 15 primes till n=50 so now i need to make combinations of those efficiently.